# Sending clipboard contents as keystrokes to terminal window in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, terminal, clipboard

Under Windows, I use Putty for remote server administration.  It has a killer feature where you can send the contents of your clipboard to the server as keystrokes, effectively letting you copy and paste directly onto an arbitrary program on a remote machine.

Is there some equivalent functionality in Linux/Ubuntu?  I'm copying a command from my local text editor and want to paste it into a remote "emacs -nw" session on a server that I have open in a terminal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copied the text by marking it with your mouse, you should be able to paste it by pressing the middle mouse button in the terminal. If you copied it using ctrl+c, pressing shift+insert in the terminal should work.